# Solución Campo Javascript con cálculos

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo que presionar dos veces un botón calcular para que el último campo salga correctamente. Hice un pequeño vídeo muy corto para que pudiesen ver a que me refiero: [Vídeo de Youtube del problema de javascript](https://youtu.be/gNPkang2d_A)
Este es mi código:

```js
//función que se ejecuta cada vez que se añade una letra en un cuadro de         texto
//suma los valores de los cuadros de texto

function sumar()
{
  var dolar = 18;
  var porcentaje = 100;
  var valor1=verificar("valor1");
  var valor2=verificar("valor2");
  var valor3=verificar("valor3");
  var valor4=verificar("valor4");
  var valor5=verificar("valor5");
  x = parseFloat(valor1);
  y = parseFloat(valor1)*parseFloat(dolar);
  z = parseFloat(valor1)/porcentaje*10;
  f = parseFloat(valor2)+parseFloat(valor4);

  // realizamos la suma de los valores y los ponemos en la casilla del
  // formulario que contiene el total

  document.getElementById("valor2").value= x;

  document.getElementById("valor3").value= y;

  document.getElementById("valor4").value= z;

  document.getElementById("valor5").value= f;

}

//función para verificar los valores de los cuadros de texto. si no es         un valor
//numérico, cambia de color el borde del cuadro de texto

function verificar(id)
{
  var obj=document.getElementById(id);
  if(obj.value=="")
    value="0";
  else
    value=obj.value;
  if(validate_importe(value,1))
  {
    // marcamos como erróneo
    obj.style.borderColor="#808080";
    return value;
  }else{
    // marcamos como erróneo
    obj.style.borderColor="#f00";
    return 0;
  }
}

//Función para validar el importe
//Tiene que recibir: El valor del importe
//Determinar si permite o no decimales
//Devuelve: true - Correcto , False - Incorrecto

function validate_importe(value,decimal)
{
  if(decimal==undefined)
    decimal=0;

  if(decimal==1)
  {
    // Permite decimales tanto por . como por ,
    var patron=new RegExp("^[0-9]+((,|\.)[0-9]{1,2})?$");
  }else{
    // Número entero normal
    var patron=new RegExp("^([0-9])*$")
    }

  if(value && value.search(patron)==0)
  {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

```css
.auto-style1 { text-align: center; }
.auto-style2 { background-image: url('img/bg_calculo_dolares.jpg');  }
.auto-style3 { border-width: 0px; }
.auto-style4 { text-align: left; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; }
.auto-style5 { font-size: 55pt; }
.auto-style6 { text-align: left; }
.auto-style7 { text-align: left; font-family: Arial,Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 55pt; }
.auto-style8 { font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; }
.auto-style9 { font-size: 55pt; font-weight: bold; }
.auto-style10 { text-align: right; }
.auto-style11 { font-size: 55pt; color: #00A743; }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
    <title>Remesas ENVIA - Calculo en dolares</title>
    <script type="text/javascript"src="/js/calculo.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body style="background-color: #F37300; margin-top: 27px; height: 1612px;">

    <table align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width: 940px; height: 1560px" class="auto-style2">
      <tr>
        <td class="auto-style1" style="width: 940px; height: 230px"         colspan="2"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="auto-style10" style="width: 538px; height: 170px;">
          <input type="number" id="valor1" size="23" style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 85pt; height: 160px; width: 410px;" required class="auto-style11">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; </td>
        <td class="auto-style1" style="width: 470px; height: 170px;">
          <img alt height="168" onclick="sumar()" src="img/button_calcula.jpg" style="float: left" width="370" class="auto-style11"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="auto-style1" style="width: 940px; height: 1110px;" colspan="2">
          <p> &nbsp;</p>
          <p class="auto-style4"><span class="auto-style5">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Si envias a Mexico</span></p>
          <div class="auto-style6"><span class="auto-style5">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <span class="auto-style8"><strong>$</strong></span></span>

            <strong>

              <input type="text" id="valor2" value="0.00" disabled value="0" size="23" style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 55pt; height: 75px; width: 335px;" required class="auto-style9"></strong>
            <span class="auto-style7">dolares</span></div>

          <p class="auto-style4"><span class="auto-style5">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; tu familia recibe</span></p>
          <div class="auto-style6"><span class="auto-style5">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <span class="auto-style8"><strong>$</strong></span></span>

            <strong>

              <input type="text" id="valor3" value="0.00" disabled value="0" size="23" style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 55pt; height: 75px; width: 335px;" required class="auto-style9"></strong>
            <span class="auto-style7">pesos,</span></div>

          <p class="auto-style4"><span class="auto-style5">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; tu envio cuesta</span></p>
          <div class="auto-style6"><span class="auto-style5">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <span class="auto-style8"><strong>$</strong></span></span>

            <strong>

              <input type="text" id="valor4" value="0.00" disabled value="0" size="23" style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 55pt; height: 75px; width: 335px;" required class="auto-style9"></strong>
            <span class="auto-style7">dolares</span></div>

          <p class="auto-style4"><span class="auto-style5">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; tu pago total es de</span></p>
          <div class="auto-style6"><span class="auto-style5">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <span class="auto-style8"><strong>$</strong></span></span>

            <strong>

              <input type="text" id="valor5" value="0.00" disabled value="0" size="23" style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 55pt; height: 75px; width: 335px;" required class="auto-style9"></strong>
            <span class="auto-style7">dolares</span></div>
          <br />
          <br />
          <a href="seleccionar_destinatario.php"><img alt height="200" src="img/button_continuar.jpg" width="850" class="auto-style3" /></a></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="auto-style1" style="width: 940px; height: 45px" colspan="2"></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: puedes crear un MVCE para mostrar el problema? un video sirve de poco...

Comment: @JordiCastilla que es MVCE?

Comment: @Drago25 https://www.google.es/search?q=MVCE&oq=MVCE&aqs=chrome..69i57.1071j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8 :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dentro de la función `sumar()` esta porción de código:

```
var dolar = 18;
var porcentaje = 100;
var valor1=verificar("valor1");
var valor2=verificar("valor2");
var valor3=verificar("valor3");
var valor4=verificar("valor4");
var valor5=verificar("valor5");
x = parseFloat(valor1);
y = parseFloat(valor1)*parseFloat(dolar);
z = parseFloat(valor1)/porcentaje*10;
f = parseFloat(valor2)+parseFloat(valor4);
```

generará resultados incorrectos para la primera vez que se llame, debido a que la operaciones para la que se está calculando el valor de `f` toma los datos indirectamente del `DOM` (a través de los llamados a las funciones `verificar()` y no está haciendo uso de los valores previamente calculados de `x`, `y`, `z`. Veamos lo que ocurre:

1. Al cargarse la página la primera vez, todos los valores de los `input` de tipo `text` son 0.0. El input de tipo `number` no tiene un valor por defecto, así que es "".
2. Al ejecutar el método `sumar()` la primera vez, los valores de `valor1` a `valor5` son los devueltos por la función `verificar()`, que, a partir del id que se le pasa como parámetro, obtiene el valor que tiene en ese momento cada input. Como todos, excepto `valor1` tienen por defecto 0.0, la verificación es correcta y `verificar()` devuelve ese mismo valor para `valor2` ... `valor5`. Para `valor1`, suponemos la entrada (en este caso 100) es correcta, por lo tanto el valor de `valor1` es 100.
3. Convierte el valor de texto '100' a tipo `float`, ahora la variable `x` es igual a 100.0
4. Multiplica el valor de texto '100' convertido a `float` con el valor de dolar convertido a `float`: ahora la variable `y` es igual a 1800 (el `parseFloat` de la variable `dolar` no es realmente necesario).
5. Divide el valor de texto '100' convertido a `float` y lo divide con el valor de la variable `porcentaje` multiplicada por 100. Ahora la variable `f` es igual a 10.
6. **Suma el valor de texto '0.0' con el valor de texto '0.0'**. ¿Por qué? porque está operando sobre las variables `valor2` y `valor4` que contienen en ese momento esos valores, y no sobre los cálculos realizados sobre las variables `y` y `z`.
7. Guarda esta información en los input respectivos.
8. La segunda vez que oprima el botón, la función `sumar()` se ejecuta nuevamente, los valores `valor1` a `valor5`, de acuerdo al procedimiento de arriba, tendrán los valores del cálculo anterior, por lo tanto, `valor2` y `valor4` tendrán los datos correctos y la variable `f` tendrá el resultado esperado.

Para corregir el error, entonces, cambie esta línea de código:

```
f = parseFloat(valor2)+parseFloat(valor4);
```

por esta otra

```
f = parseFloat(x)+parseFloat(z);
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta y por dejarme bien en claro el uso de cada cosa y todo lo que hace,Gracias.